# css hide span after input

Tags: html, css, forms, hide

Hi I am trying to hide a span after an input field with the following code:

```
 <style>
 input~span:after { opacity: 0;}
 </style>
 ...
 <input type="email" />
 <span>Test</span>
```

But the span is still shown in the browser HOWEVER if I inspect the element with firebug,
it tells me that the span has opacity: 0;

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why `:after` ? That is for creating pseudoelements..

```
<style>
    input~span{ opacity: 0;}
</style>
```

Comment: 1. display: none does not work either.
2. I'm using :after because I want to hide all divs after certain input fields

Comment: `div`? You realise you've said `span` in your question, and the code therein?

Comment: @gries, that is not what [`:after` *W3C specs*](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-elements/:after) is for.. See this example that works .. http://jsfiddle.net/ZS9C7/